# Is it correct to use "helps" as the plural form of the noun "help"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, nouns, grammatical-number

I've heard some people use "helps" as the plural form of "help". Is that correct? Or are there any exceptions?

Comment: What did you find when looking this up in a dictionary or usage guide?

Comment: I couldn't find anything regarding this matter

Comment: Where have you seen *helps* used as a noun? Please provide written examples, because this does not appear to be English.

Comment: Yesterday I was reading a news paper article about a church, they have given some guidelines for using their website. I saw it says "usage helps". I'm sorry, I don't recall the name of that particular news paper.

Comment: Perhaps that was a verb not a noun? That is, they were saying that usage helps do something or other. That would account for *help* being used as *helps*: it would be a singular verb. I have “never” heard of it being used as a plural verb.

Comment: Yeah. You're correct. It should be. May be they have made a mistake. Thanks anyway

Comment: Helps in the plural is normally used for physical things like books, study guides, etc. (not that its correct usage, but I've heard it used that way, "study helps" as referring to study guides not merely the statement that "study helps").  Help in the abstract remains singular.

Comment: @developerwjk Just as one can verb any noun, one can countnoun any massnoun, but you shouldn't expect many happinesses from peoples who catch you at it.

Answer (score 2):

"Helps" is not commonly used as the plural form of help.

Places where we can use 'helps' is for 3rd person present tense.

Consider the following example:(taken from sentence.yourdictionary.com)

> > Howie is a very good guy who helps catch the bad ones.

Help can be used either as a verb or noun depending on the context, but not usually used as plural form.

There may be very few exceptions (source: Wiktionary)

help ‎(usually uncountable, plural helps)

(usually uncountable) Something or someone which provides assistance with a task.

> > I've printed out a list of math helps.

Usage Notes:

> > The sense "people employed to help in the maintenance of a house" is usually an uncountable mass noun. A countable form - "a hired help", "two hired helps" - is attested, but now less common.

Hence except for study helps and house helps it is not used in other cases in general.

Answer (score -2):

Saw "Helps" as a noun today. Saw in the Preface of "The New Standard Alphabetical Indexed Bible Holy Bible Authorized Or King James Version). (1963)(1969-70 Edition)

Comment: This is a bit hard to read. Can you add punctuation? And can you add a reference and version of the Bible? Even though it's prepared by "notable Bible scholars", it may not use modern English.

Comment: Sorry I English is not my. First language. I added some pictures though to help clarify so definitely take a look at them include the name of God in 48 languages

Comment: I don't see "helps" in there...where is it?